# Spring Security Custom Login Function

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin

I am working on a Vaadin/Spring application. For login it is suggested to use Spring Security. Following the docs [1] I have setup spring security. Right now I am using `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` with hard coded username/password in the app.

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
            User.withUsername("user")
                    .password("{noop}pass")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Everything works with this setup however for logging I have call a external function that returns a boolean with the supplied username/password pair and non of the built in managers allow this.

```
canLogin(user,pass);
```

This in turn calls an external service. How can I setup spring security to allow this?

[1] https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/modern-web-apps-with-spring-boot-and-vaadin/adding-a-login-screen-to-a-vaadin-app-with-spring-security

Comment: So you just get a boolean. No user information?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Exactly just a bollean that indicates success or failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Baeldung article [Spring Security Authentication Provider](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider) has an example that I think suits your needs.

Simply create your own authentication provider that authenticates as you see fit, and then register it in your security configuration.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationService myAuthenticationService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {
 
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        
        if (myAuthenticationService.canLogin(name, password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```